# Bitbaking meta-mender-core error Apalis Imx6?

Tags: bitbake, imx6, mender

I want to install mender on my device Imx6, for that I added the layer meta-mender-core successfully, but when I try to bitbake vim for example I get:

```
rama@RR06:/oe-core/build$ bitbake vim
NOTE: Trying for parse version info from: gcc version 5.2.1 20151005 (Linaro GCC 5.2-2015.11-2) 
NOTE: Trying for parse version info from: gcc version 5.2.1 20151005 (Linaro GCC 5.2-2015.11-2) 
NOTE: Trying for parse version info from: gcc version 5.2.1 20151005 (Linaro GCC 5.2-2015.11-2) 
Loading cache: 100% |#########################################################################################| ETA:  00:00:00
Loaded 983 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Error during finalise of /home/rama/repositories/meta-mender/meta-mender-core/recipes-mender/mender-artifact/mender-artifact_2.1.1.bb
NOTE: Error during finalise of /home/rama/repositories/meta-mender/meta-mender-core/recipes-mender/mender-artifact/mender-artifact_2.0.0.bb
NOTE: Error during finalise of /home/rama/repositories/meta-mender/meta-mender-core/recipes-mender/mender-artifact/mender-artifact_2.0.1.bb
NOTE: Error during finalise of /home/rama/repositories/meta-mender/meta-mender-core/recipes-mender/mender-artifact/mender-artifact_git.bb
NOTE: Error during finalise of /home/rama/repositories/meta-mender/meta-mender-core/recipes-mender/mender-artifact/mender-artifact_1.0.0.bb
NOTE: Error during finalise of /home/rama/repositories/meta-mender/meta-mender-core/recipes-mender/mender-artifact/mender-artifact_2.0.2.bb
NOTE: Error during finalise of /home/rama/repositories/meta-mender/meta-mender-core/recipes-mender/mender-artifact/mender-artifact_2.1.0.bb
NOTE: Error during finalise of /home/rama/repositories/meta-mender/meta-mender-core/recipes-mender/mender/mender_1.3.0b1.bb
NOTE: Error during finalise of /home/rama/repositories/meta-mender/meta-mender-core/recipes-mender/mender/mender_1.2.1.bb
NOTE: Error during finalise of /home/rama/repositories/meta-mender/meta-mender-core/recipes-mender/mender/mender_1.1.1.bb
NOTE: Error during finalise of /home/rama/repositories/meta-mender/meta-mender-core/recipes-mender/mender/mender_git.bb
ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing /home/rama/repositories/meta-mender/meta-mender-core/recipes-mender/mender-artifact/mender-artifact_1.0.0.bb: Failure expanding variable GOPTESTBUILDFLAGS: SkipPackage: Unsupported CPU architecture: ${TUNE_ARCH}
NOTE: Error during finalise of /home/rama/repositories/meta-mender/meta-mender-core/recipes-mender/mender/mender_1.1.0.bb
NOTE: Error during finalise of /home/rama/repositories/meta-mender/meta-mender-core/recipes-mender/mender/mender_1.0.0.bb
NOTE: Error during finalise of /home/rama/repositories/meta-mender/meta-mender-core/recipes-mender/mender/mender_1.2.0.bb
NOTE: Error during finalise of /home/rama/repositories/meta-mender/meta-mender-core/recipes-mender/mender/mender_1.0.1.bb
NOTE: Error during finalise of /home/rama/repositories/meta-mender/meta-mender-core/recipes-mender/mender/mender_1.1.2.bb

Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

If I remove the meta-mender-core layer, vim bakes successfully.

I use Ubuntu 14.04, and the branch of mender is pyro

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't been sure*, but I think that the problem based on incompatible versions between poky and meta-mender-core.

This error tell's us that *bitbake* couldn't find definition of this variable *GOPTESTBUILDFLAGS*.

I'm assume that You are using pyro branch on poky or older, and there in *go.bbclass* definition of *GOPTESTBUILDFLAGS* in next release it's appear [rocko go.bbclass](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/classes/go.bbclass?h=rocko#n44). My proposal is to try update poky version to rocko branch.

With latest versions of poky, meta-mender-core and with meta-oe ([here is vim recipe](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/5559/)) I was able to 'bake' *vim* with this configuration layers.

*After changing to pyro branch (meta-mender-core) I couldn't find in any other files used *GOPTESTBUILDFLAGS* variable for reproduce this issue.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I may also add that I had some issues with some go files, so I had to manually create them and copy paste them. Do you think this was the problem?

Comment: I replaced the go.bbclass with the one from poky, because I wanted it to be consistent, i now get the same error with variable GOBIN_FINAL